# post_delete gets a different path than pre_save

Tags: python, django

I have a pre_save function that deletes an image after a user is deleted, but it doesn't work unless I change it to post_delete:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def delete_file(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Deletes image files on `post_delete` """
    if instance.image:
        path = instance.image.path
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            os.remove(path)
```

When I change pre_save to post_delete It gets the right path which is /media/images/image.png but in pre_save it gets /media/image.png which is incorrect.

Comment: When you save a `user`, do you change the image field?